# How to add minute marker in Microsoft Stream in comment?

Tags: microsoft-office, video-streaming

How do you create a minute marker comment in Microsoft Streams?
I am trying to add a marked up link in the comment, but you can only edit using normal text.

Comment: Please refer to this post : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-forum/stream-feature-request-add-a-timecode-in-a-comment/m-p/176482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows stream is just like YouTube, just type in the comment the time marker like 11:15 to mean the eleventh minute 15th seconds and it will automatically interpreted as a minute marker.